# Default value for user ForeignKey with Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Is there any way I can set the default value of this field to automatically select the logged in user? I know you can do this in the save method but my client has requested that it automatically defaults to the logged in user at edit time to avoid confusion.

[This article](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/) goes into how to update it during save, just not at edit time.

Comment: what is "edit time"? i mean, the article is edited when it's saved, isn't it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'author':
            kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs
        )
```

Comment: Just a side note: I think you don't need this line `return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)` in a general case.

Comment: I think @naktinis right and when you don't use it, grappelli's autocomplete_lookup_fields works

Comment: Thanks - I agree and removed the line.

Comment: The block works fine if used within the Inline class, used in the ModelAdmin it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the Admin part of your model to not display the author if the object that you are editing is new because it should be set to the current user and only if you are editing an object does the field show?

You would do this by overriding the get_form method of ModelAdmin.