# Defining Default Inline value for Django Admin forms?

Tags: django, django-admin

If I have an inline admin class like this:

```
class ResourceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Resource
    extra = 3
```

Is there any way to specify the default values for the 3 "extra" resources because the manual says that the `prepopulated_fields` doesn't accept ForeignKey fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) and set the initial value of your fields.

Check this answer to get the basic idea: [Default value for user ForeignKey with Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632848/django-default-value-for-user-foreignkey-with-django-admin/5633217#5633217)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create default values for your inline extra models by targeting the parent admin class that uses ResourceInline as it's inline.

All you have to do is override the add_view function on the parent admin class:
[Customize Django Admin: Add More Than One Default Inline on Parent Add_View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972661/customize-django-admin-add-more-than-one-default-inline-on-parent-add-view)