# Customize Django Admin: Add More Than One Default Inline on Parent Add_View

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an admin model with a few inline models included with it (see the **ResourceUserAdmin** model below for full class):

```py
    inlines = [ 
            ResourceLocationInlineAdmin ,
            ResourceCategoryInlineAdmin , 
            ResourceStageInlineAdmin ,
          ]
```

When a user clicks to create a new **ResourceUserAdmin**  I want the inlines of the class **ResourceCategoryInlineAdmin** to get initial values -- note that these relationships will not be saved to the database. I've tried to override parts of the **add_view** function to get what i want but I can't figure out how to pass multiple inline forms back to parent.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**Models**

```py
class ResourceUserAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    inlines = [ 
            ResourceLocationInlineAdmin ,
            ResourceCategoryInlineAdmin , 
            ResourceStageInlineAdmin ,
          ]

    list_display = ( 
                 'user' , 
                 'name' ,
                 'state' ,
                 'email' ,
                 'website' ,
                 'phone' ,
                 'logo_url_link',
    )

    search_fields = ( 'name' , 'email' , 'website'  )

    list_filter = ( 'name' , 'state' , 'email' , 'website' )

    ordering = ( 'name', )

     fields = ( 
             'user' , 
             'name' ,
             'state' ,
             'email' ,
             'website' ,
             'phone' ,
             'logo' ,
             'ideal_candidate',
    )
admin.site.register( ResourceUser, ResourceUserAdmin )
```

Here is the inline model I want to create many by default:

```py
class ResourceCategoryInlineAdmin( admin.StackedInline ):
    model = ResourceCategory
    extra = 0

class ResourceCategoryAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    list_display = ( 'user' ,
                     'category' , )

    ordering = ( 'user' , )
    fields = ( 'user' , 'category' )

    def formfield_for_foreignkey( self, db_field, *args, **kwargs ):
        if isinstance( db_field, models.ForeignKey ):
            if db_field.name == 'category':
                kwargs['widget'] = forms.RadioSelect()
        return super( ResourceCategoryAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey( db_field, **kwargs )

admin.site.register( ResourceCategory, ResourceCategoryAdmin )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution, though not the option i really wanted to use. You can do it by overriding the the whole **add_view** function and setting the intial attributes for each form in the formsets (look for the override comment below)

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    "The 'add' admin view for this model."
    model = self.model
    opts = model._meta

    if not self.has_add_permission(request):
        raise PermissionDenied

    ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
    formsets = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_object = self.save_form(request, form, change=False)
            form_validated = True
        else:
            form_validated = False
            new_object = self.model()
        prefixes = {}
        for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request), self.inline_instances):
            prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
            prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
            if prefixes[prefix] != 1:
                prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
            formset = FormSet(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,
                              instance=new_object,
                              save_as_new="_saveasnew" in request.POST,
                              prefix=prefix, queryset=inline.queryset(request))
            formsets.append(formset)
        if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
            self.save_model(request, new_object, form, change=False)
            form.save_m2m()
            for formset in formsets:
                self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=False)

            self.log_addition(request, new_object)
            return self.response_add(request, new_object)
    else:
        # Prepare the dict of initial data from the request.
        # We have to special-case M2Ms as a list of comma-separated PKs.
        initial = dict(request.GET.items())
        for k in initial:
            logger.info( "for k in initial, k = %s" % k )
            try:
                f = opts.get_field(k)
            except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
                continue
            if isinstance(f, models.ManyToManyField):
                initial[k] = initial[k].split(",")
        form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
        prefixes = {}
        for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request),
                                   self.inline_instances):
            prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
            prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
            if prefixes[prefix] != 1:
                prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])

            formset = FormSet(instance=self.model(), prefix=prefix, queryset=inline.queryset(request))

            #
            #
            # override the inlines of my choice
            # to create initial values
            #
            #
            if inline.__class__.__name__ == 'ResourceCategoryInlineAdmin':
                for frm, category in zip( formset, Category.objects.all() ):
                   frm.fields['category'].initial = category

            formsets.append(formset)

    adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
        self.prepopulated_fields, self.get_readonly_fields(request),
        model_admin=self)
    media = self.media + adminForm.media

    inline_admin_formsets = []
    for inline, formset in zip(self.inline_instances, formsets):
        fieldsets = list(inline.get_fieldsets(request))
        readonly = list(inline.get_readonly_fields(request))
        inline_admin_formset = helpers.InlineAdminFormSet(inline, formset,
            fieldsets, readonly, model_admin=self)
        inline_admin_formsets.append(inline_admin_formset)
        media = media + inline_admin_formset.media

    context = {
        'title': _('Add %s') % force_unicode(opts.verbose_name),
        'adminform': adminForm,
        'is_popup': "_popup" in request.REQUEST,
        'show_delete': False,
        'media': mark_safe(media),
        'inline_admin_formsets': inline_admin_formsets,
        'errors': helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
        'root_path': self.admin_site.root_path,
        'app_label': opts.app_label,
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url=form_url, add=True)
    #return super(ResourceUserAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```