# Django AdminModel add_view prepopulated fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a simple model being displayed in the admin. In the add view I have 4 fields, with the first field being a foreign key to user. I need to:

1. Pre-populate the user field.
2. Make the field read only.

I cannot find any documentation on this. I looked at the following links:

- [django admin "add page" initial datetime from GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559771/django-admin-add-page-initial-datetime-from-get-parameters),
- [Customize Django Admin: Add More Than One Default Inline on Parent Add_View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972661/customize-django-admin-add-more-than-one-default-inline-on-parent-add-view/11076996#11076996)

EDIT:
I found a solution for my first problem here; [Djanjo admin: Prefill data when clicking the add-another button next to a ForeignKey dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272712/djanjo-admin-prefill-data-when-clicking-the-add-another-button-next-to-a-foreig)

Comment: Do you want the user field to be prepopulated with the current user (i.e. the person adding the object)?

Comment: No, I want the field to be populated with the user tied to that object. The admin would be adding the object.

Comment: That has been solved. Making a field readonly from the add view is what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to add jQuery for prepopulate that particular field. Create your own js script file inside static directory of your app & just extend `change_form.html` of admin site. For example if you want add `script.js` script into your add template, your extended `change_form.html` will look like as follows:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'qb/js/formset_handlers.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```